# 360 on iOS by using a image sequence

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ipad

I got a sequence of images and I'd like to create something like this:

http://www.apple.com/html5/showcase/threesixty/

Google wasn't my friend at all. Which class/lib should I use?

Thanks!

Comment: You might wanna try http://gardengnomesoftware.com/pano2vr.php or http://krpano.com/iphone/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up creating my own view for that. Here's a download link in case anybody needs to do this.

http://www.fvalente.org/blog/2011/12/19/fvimagesequence-for-mac-os-xios/